# Unity script - code is executed no in oder. How do I turn off multithreading?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What do I mean by code not executing in order. I have the following code:

```
IEnumerator Game(){
// do something
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(10f);
// do something else
Debug.Log("game method")
}

void Start(){

// some code ..

StartCoroutine(Game());

// other code ..

Debug.Log("end of the code");
Debug.Log("something else");
}
```

For some reason I will get in the console this:

```
end of the code
something else
game method
```

**I guess it is something related to multithreading. How do I turn it off (How do I avoid it)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's executing in order.

your code should look like this :

```
void Start()
{  
StartCoroutine(Game());
}

IEnumerator Game(){
// do something
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(10f);
// do something else
Debug.Log("game method")

ExecuteLast();
}

void ExecuteLast()
{
Debug.Log("end of the code");
Debug.Log("something else");
}
```